# Perl, can't capture return codes?

Tags: perl, return-value

and thank you in advance.
I am not a Perl developer, however, I'm really falling for Perl.  like bash/unix scripting, powerful.. I want to learn it as my scripting language, however, at this time I don't have that time.

my problem is return codes.

Problem Description:
I use Nagios Core for monitoring.  I have a task to monitor log files on a remote server and when a certain statement exists in log, pull that line, extract the file name, and copy this file back to an ingestion endpoint.  I'm using the Nagios Plugin written in Perl, Check_logfiles. A really excellent and powerful plugin.  I can write hook in scripts in Perl to perform tasks on events triggered.

here is my Plugin script written as a subroutine call in the check_logfiles configuration.

```
$scriptpath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\contrib';
$protocolsdir = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\protocols';
$seekfilesdir = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\seek';

$MACROS = {
    LOGS_DIR => 'C:\APMConnect\Logs',
    PP_INGESTION_EP => 'C:\APMConnect\AutoDataLoader\Scandir\ManageAPM',
    SRC_DIR => 'E:\Zip File Archive'
};

#$postscript = 'custom_mail_alert.pl';
#$postscriptparams = '--sender alpcts000000881@ge.com --recpt gary.l.mills@ge.com --subject "Notification - APM Loader refeed performed" --message "$CL_SERVICEOUTPUT$" --log-file "C:\APMConnect\Logs\AutoLoader.log" --send_if_rc_gt 1 --display-name "Aviation Preprocessor Notification"';
#$postscriptstdin = '$CL_HOSTNAME$\t$CL_SERVICEDESC$\t$CL_SERVICESTATEID$\t$CL_SERVICEOUTPUT$\n';
    
@searches = (
  {
    tag => '504 Gateway Time-Out',
    logfile => '$LOGS_DIR$\AutoLoader.log',
    rotation => 'AutoLoader.log.\d{1,2}',
    type => 'rotating',
    criticalpatterns => [
        '^java.lang.Exception:Method failed: HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Time-out Please check configuration details and replace or update the file :.*'
    ],
    options => 'protocol,perfdata,script,supersmartscript',
    script => sub {
        use File::Copy;
        
        $map_drive = 'C:\Windows\System32\net.exe use E: \\win.alphp031.corp.bp.com\APM_Data_Storage /USER:lp814555sv xnEDs7PaD3g /PERSISTENT:YES';
        my $status = system("$map_drive 2>&1");
        my $exit_code = ($status >> 8) & 0xff;
        
#       if ( $exit_code!=0 ) {
#           printf "Exit Code: $exit_code\n";
#           printf "Status: $status\n";
#           printf 'CRITICAL - APM Data Storage NAS Share Cannot be mounted!';
#           return 2;
#       }
#       my $file_name = "BHPJanFP_2018-06-25-06-43-09.csv";
#       my $source_dir = 'C:\Users\212555427\TEMP\A';
        my $target_dir = 'C:\Users\212555427\TEMP\B';
#       my $sout = 'java.lang.Exception:Method failed: HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Time-out Please check configuration details and replace or update the file : \\ALPCTS000000881\Archivedir\PROCESS_ADL\FaultData20200826144206065.zip';
        
        my $_source_dir = $ENV{CHECK_LOGFILES_SRC_DIR};
        my $_target_dir = $ENV{CHECK_LOGFILES_PP_INGESTION_EP};
        my $sout = $ENV{CHECK_LOGFILES_SERVICEOUTPUT};
        my $result = rindex($sout, 'FaultData');
        my $_file_name = substr($sout, $result, length($sout));
        opendir(my $DIR, $_source_dir) || die "Can't opendir $_source_dir: $!"; 

        if( -f "$_source_dir/$_file_name" ) {
            copy ("$_source_dir\\$_file_name", "$target_dir\\$_file_name") || die "File Copy Failed: $!";
            if ( $? == 0 ) {
                printf 'OK - File Copy Successful!';
                printf " Copied File to Refeed APM: $_source_dir\\$_file_name";
                return 0;
            } else {
                printf 'CRITICAL - File Copy Failed!';
                printf " Source dir: $_source_dir\\$_file_name";
                return 2;
            }
        } else {
            printf 'CRITICAL - File Copy Failed, File CANNOT be located!';
            printf "Source dir: $_source_dir\\$_file_name";
            return 2;
        }
        closedir($DIR);
    }
  }
);
```

my problem starts here, with mapping the NAS drive. I do not know how to get and or manipolate the return codes. because there is a condition that the NAS drive is already mounted and therefore in use.
I want to allow the execution if this condition exists ALSO if it has successfully mounted.

```
my $status = system("$map_drive 2>&1");
```

when the disk is already mounted I get this

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\plugins\check_logfiles-3.12\plugins-scripts>check_logf
check_logfiles.cfg"
System error 85 has occurred.

The local device name is already in use.

CRITICAL - (1 errors in check_logfiles.protocol-2020-09-24-13-40-27) - 
Exit Code: 2
Status: 512
```

I need to continue execution for this state and the state of 0 or successful mount.

how do you capture these return codes?

so I essentually need something like psuedo code...

```
my $status = system("$map_drive 2>&1");
if ( $status != 0 || $status != rc = System error 85 has occurred ) {
   printf 'CRITICAL - APM Data Storage NAS Share Cannot be mounted!';
   return 2;  (*** 2 here is for Nagios )
```

I found the  return codes to system I believe, can't find for net command ?
from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-

ERROR_ALREADY_ASSIGNED

85 (0x55)

The local device name is already in use.

but after doing ...
my $status = system("$map_drive 2>&1");
my $exit_code = ($status >> 8) & 0xff;

for the condition that ALREADY IN USE or mounted already I get '2'.

to ensure that all other conditons the call breaks out or exits and the two GOOD conditions allow to process or execute.

I hope this makes sense, please let me know, and thank you !!!

Comment: thanks Schwern, yeah, my problem too, Windows... arg!  I tried looking for the text but unsuccessful.

Comment: Confirm that you are using `use strict; use warnings;`. Otherwise, add those and fix errors and fatal errors that they produce, or show the errors here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system` returns the exit code of the process, also in `$?`.

[`$^E`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables) returns the "extended OS error" and is used on operating systems which have separate ways of returning process error codes. On Windows, this is the result of [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) which gives [system error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-).

> Under Win32, $^E always returns the last error information
> reported by the Win32 call "GetLastError()" which describes the
> last error from within the Win32 API. Most Win32-specific code
> will report errors via $^E. ANSI C and Unix-like calls set "errno"
> and so most portable Perl code will report errors via $!.

So your check should be something like...

```
my $exit = system("$map_drive 2>&1");
my $error = $^E;
if ( $exit != 0 || $error == 85 ) {
```

I've renamed $status to avoid confusion. And I've assigned $^E to a lexical variable because it is a global and will be overwritten by another system call.

Comment: Thanks so much Schwern, I can try this tomorrow and get right back with you. learning a new language is always embarrassing, so much the same done differently :) but thank you !!!

Comment: something is goofy. this doesn't work.  gives... Exit Code: 512, error: The system cannot find the file specified. AND again...  Exit Code: 512, error: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.   STILL NOT getting good return codes to make a decision on.

Comment: @GLMills You printed `$^E` and got the same as `$?`, 512? Could you show a `perl -v` please?

Comment: Not related to this question, but @Schwern, have you received my recent emails about Method::Signatures and Mite?

Comment: hey guys sorry, and thank you !! had a little misfortune, but I'm back :) - hey, well, It turns out what I'm experiencing is the NAS Share implementaton and security.  They mapped / mounted the drive not with persistance, not without needing uid/pwd.  The disk and security rules are the problem here.  Thank you for showing me how to get the Win last error response from Perl.  now to get the drive properly mapped.  thank you all!